# phonegap IOS distribution certificates error

Tags: ios, cordova, certificate

I have used a distribution .p12 file and `myDistribution.mobileprovision` file, but when built it gives that error:

```
Error - No codesigning identities found matching the provided provisioning profile: 
No codesigning identities found: 
No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match 
the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (�Distribution�) were found. 
- You can fix this here
```